# How to view entire file without downloading it using SharePoint REST API?

Tags: javascript, .net, rest, sharepoint

I am a fresher who just started working as an integration developer. I am working on integrating Sharepoint and our CRM application. Is there a possibility to just "view" entire file instead of downloading it? The CRM application uses Javascript and C#.Net. I have tried a few ways but all of these seem to download the file or there are options to view just the thumbnail.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I assume you're talking about showing the file in the browser instead of saving it to the hard drive? What type of file are we talking about?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. The file can be any type.

Comment: The browser can't handle most file types. Only very few. Basically HTML/XML, a few *(and I mean just very few)* Image/Video/Audio formats and PDF *(through a built-in PDF.js)*. Also files that contain just text, like json, csv, ... not pretty but readable. So again, what file types are you trying to render and what application do you usually use to open these files?

Comment: Thank you for your time. If handling all file types is not viable, then may be jpeg, png, pdf, docx could be part of our MVP. The CRM is a web application, so I was thinking on clicking the file link, we can make an api call to share point, get the file and render it in a new tab on the browser. Is it possible?